# Different order items and layout with css3 by resolution with the same html

Tags: css, layout

I don´t manage to get a responsive result keeping the same HTML layout.

I need :

1. two different block orders if the screen width is before or after 1024px,
2. => 1024px, I have to display items organized in two columns and make sure blocks 1, 2, 3 are inside the left column and blocks 4, 5 are inside the right column (the height of the wrapper has to fit of the content ),
3. < 1024px, all blocks are inside unique column but the order is different.

Like this...

### 1024px and more

[image]

### 1023px and less

[image]

### Current CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
    .production-container{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
        padding: 0 var(--standard-margin) 0 var(--standard-margin);
        justify-content: stretch;
        min-height: 200px;
    }

    aside.production-block{
        max-width: 100vw;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex: 1;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin: 24px 0;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
        break-inside: avoid;
    }

    .production-container > .production-block-4 {
        order: 1;
    }

    .production-container > .production-block-1 {
        order: 2;
    }

    .production-container > .production-block-2 {
        order: 3;
    }

    .production-container > .production-block-5 {
        order: 4;
    }

    .production-container > .production-block-3 {
        order: 5;
    }

}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {

   .production-container{
        column-count: 2;
        column-gap: 50px;
        max-width: 1024px;
        background: linear-gradient( var(--text-light-color), var(--text-light-color) ) no-repeat center/1px 100%; /* vertical line in the center */
   }
   .production-block {
        margin: 0 0 10px 0;
        break-inside: avoid;
        max-width: 520px;
    }

}
```

The most important problem is, in the biggest resolution, I don´t manage to force each block to be on the first or second column, they place thereself naturally based on height content. Maybe, I should change of css strategy compatible with the smallest resolution but when I used "grid", each row got a height that made big blank spaces.

Someone has got an idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can switch from a grid layout to a column CSS layout (untill masonry  CSS grid layout is widely avalaible https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Masonry_Layout , here is an example https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ExXNXdd For FF at this time if activated)

Demo from your HTML code in the snippet lower below **withouth blank space**

How does it work ?

- 1 - **< 1024px** `grid` for the single column to use order *(grid creates a single column if no template is set)*
- 2 -  **> 1023px** `column-count` and `display:block`  for a 2 column layout . `break-after:always` & `break-before: column` will be avalaible for browsers using the chrome engine (see [CSS Fragmentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Fragmentation) ).
- 3 - For firefox & **>1023px**  a  hudge `margin-bottom` on the third element, so there can be **only 3 on the first column**. This margin won't be applied inside the container, npr will be overflowing it, it will only push the fourth on the next column.
  Firefox can be filtered via  (untill it understands `break-after:always` with Column CSS) to apply the margin trick only for Firefox browsers use :

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  .grid > div:nth-child(3) {
   margin-bottom:100%;
   }
}
```

Live Example where the **main container takes only the height needed** to wrap the 2 columns, no matter the height of the children, you will notice that on the second example, where col 2 is taller, Chrome(s) seem  follows the breaking rules, the first column do not need to be the tallest one.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1em;
  border:solid;
  background:gray;
    
}

.grid > div:nth-child(1) {
  order: 1;
}
.grid > div:nth-child(2) {
  order: 2;
}
.grid > div:nth-child(3) {
  order: 4;
}
.grid > div:nth-child(4) {
  order: 0;
}
.grid > div:nth-child(5) {
  order: 3;

}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .grid {
    display: block;
    column-count: 2;
  }
  .grid > div {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
  }
  .grid > div:nth-child(3) {
    break-after:always;
  }
  .grid> div:nth-child(4) {
      break-before: column;
      }
  @-moz-document url-prefix() {
    .grid > div:nth-child(3) {
    margin-bottom:100%;/* trick for FF that won't show that margin if the last inside a column but not in the last column */
  }
}
}

/* demo */
.grid {
  counter-reset: divs;
}
.grid > div {
  display: grid;
}
.grid > div::before {
  counter-increment: divs;
  content: counter(divs);
  color: white;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: clamp(10px, 5vmin, 30px);
}
.grid > div:nth-child(1) {
  background: #fa9917;
  height: 100px;
}
.grid > div:nth-child(2) {
  background: #33e0fe;
  height: 160px;
}
.grid > div:nth-child(3) {
  background: #ff3366;
  height: 80px;
}
.grid > div:nth-child(4) {
  background: #2bc940;
  height: 80px;
}
.grid > div:nth-child(5) {
  background: #3399fe;
  height: 160px;
}
```

```html
<div class=grid>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
Hello the world
<hr>
Make second column taller to see where the fourth stands before you test or ask ;)
<div class=grid>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div style="height:600px"></div>
</div>
```

Finally, i would advise to use a tiny bit of javascript, or the well known and solid masonry library to avoid that FF CSS tricks. Tricks can become obsolete anytime ;)

- No idea about Safari behavior about CSS Fragmentation.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Fragmentation
>
> CSS Fragmentation is a module of CSS that defines how content is displayed when it is broken (fragmented) across multiple pages, regions, **or columns**.
>
> Fragmentation occurs when an inline box wraps onto multiple lines. It also occurs when a block spans more than one column inside a column layout container, or spans a page break when printed. Each piece of the rendering for the element **is called a fragment**.

about the native CSS grid masonry, you can see & read : https://www.smashingmagazine.com/native-css-masonry-layout-css-grid/

Answer (score 0):

Actually it works, you're almost done.
Just add the orders to:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {

   .production-container{
        column-count: 2;
        column-gap: 50px;
        max-width: 1024px;
        background: linear-gradient( var(--text-light-color), var(--text-light-color) ) no-repeat center/1px 100%; /* vertical line in the center */
   }
   
   .production-block {
        margin: 0 0 10px 0;
        break-inside: avoid;
        max-width: 520px;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
    
    .production-container > .production-block-4 {
        order: 1;
    }

    .production-container > .production-block-1 {
        order: 2;
    }

    .production-container > .production-block-2 {
        order: 3;
    }

    .production-container > .production-block-5 {
        order: 4;
    }

    .production-container > .production-block-3 {
        order: 5;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work, because in this case that depends of the height block.
I would like to be sure a block is on the correct column even if a block is removed or the height is doubled.

Comment: In your example, there is nothing which says "until 3 the block is inside the left column".

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with `grid-template-areas`.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {

   .production-container{
        height: 100%;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-areas: "zone-row1-column1 zone-row1-column2" "zone-row2-column1 zone-row2-column2" "zone-row3-column1 zone-row3-column2";
        grid-template-rows: minmax(290px, auto) 1fr;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
        grid-gap: 50px;
        max-width: 1024px;
        background: linear-gradient( var(--text-light-color), var(--text-light-color) ) no-repeat center/1px 100%; /* vertical line in the center */
   }
    
    .production-container > .production-block-4 {
        grid-area: zone-row1-column2;
    }

    .production-container > .production-block-1 {
         grid-area: zone-row1-column1;
    }

    .production-container > .production-block-2 {
        grid-area: zone-row2-column1;
    }

    .production-container > .production-block-5 {
        grid-area: zone-row2-column2;
    }

    .production-container > .production-block-3 {
        grid-area: zone-row3-column1;
    }
}
```

> You must add "zone-row3-column2" even if it does not use inside `grid-template-areas` because there are 2 columns anyway.

Comment: This solution has got a problem : if the area has no content, it does not collapsed but make a blank space.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    .production-container{      
       padding: 0 var(--standard-margin) 0 var(--standard-margin);      
       min-height: 200px;
    }
    
    .production-block {
        border: 1px solid blue;
        width:50%;
    }
    .production-block-1{
        float: left;
        clear:left
    }
    .production-block-2{
        float: left;
        clear:left
    }
    .production-block-3{
        float: left;
        clear:left
    }
    .production-block-4{
        margin-left:50%
    }
    .production-block-5{
        margin-left:50%
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to use grid for the bigger resolution. The block order doesn't depend on their height.

Comment: You should add your comment to introduce this proposition. I will try it.

Comment: Maybe that works for a specific order in html but for me I got blocks for the right side not aligned  with the top of the container.

Answer (score 0):

> I don´t manage to force each block to be on the first or second
> column, they place thereself naturally based on height content.

In that case, you can manage the **grid** with `grid-row-start` and `grid-row-end`

> when I used "grid", each row got a height that made big blank spaces.

For this solution you try to set *height* with `height: min-content`. If the block doesn't have any contents it's collapse. But, should be remember about *padding*, they give extra height without the content.

```css
*,
::after,
::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

:root {
  --bg1: hsl(34, 96%, 54%);
  --bg2: hsl(189, 99%, 60%);
  --bg3: hsl(345, 100%, 60%);
  --bg4: hsl(128, 65%, 48%);
  --bg5: hsl(210, 99%, 60%);
  --standard-margin: 1rem;
}

.production-block-1,
.production-block-2,
.production-block-3,
.production-block-4,
.production-block-5 {
  height: min-content;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.production-block-1 {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  background-color: var(--bg1);
}

.production-block-2 {
  grid-row-start: 3;
  background-color: var(--bg2);
}

.production-block-3 {
  grid-row-start: 5;
  background-color: var(--bg3);
}

.production-block-4 {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  background-color: var(--bg4);
}

.production-block-5 {
  grid-row-start: 4;
  background-color: var(--bg5);
}

.production-container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
  .production-container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
    padding: 0 var(--standard-margin) 0 var(--standard-margin);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .production-container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
  .production-block-1 {
    grid-row-start: 1;
  }
  .production-block-2 {
    grid-row-start: 2;
  }
  .production-block-3 {
    grid-row-start: 3;
  }
  .production-block-4 {
    grid-row-start: 1;
  }
  .production-block-5 {
    grid-row-start: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="production-container">
  <div class="production-block-1">1</div>
  <div class="production-block-2">2</div>
  <div class="production-block-3">3</div>
  <div class="production-block-4">4</div>
  <div class="production-block-5">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is the best solution but not the perfect one because if on the same row, the content height are differents, the grid system still make blank space ; the block above the smallest one does not go up but it´ align on its row. That is one of my problem. I made a workaround inserting dynamically the `grid-row-start` number in the template (PHP)

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution that used grid to make two columns.

> Notice : when you use grid, that forces the template to be aligned with columns and rows as well that can make blank space when blocks on the same row have not a similar height...

**Template that makes blank spaces**

```css
*,
::after,
::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

:root {
  --bg1: hsl(34, 96%, 54%);
  --bg2: hsl(189, 99%, 60%);
  --bg3: hsl(345, 100%, 60%);
  --bg4: hsl(128, 65%, 48%);
  --bg5: hsl(210, 99%, 60%);
  --standard-margin: 1rem;
}

.production-block-1,
.production-block-2,
.production-block-3,
.production-block-4,
.production-block-5 {
  height: min-content;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.production-block-1 {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  background-color: var(--bg1);
}

.production-block-2 {
  grid-row-start: 3;
  background-color: var(--bg2);
}

.production-block-3 {
  grid-row-start: 5;
  background-color: var(--bg3);
}

.production-block-4 {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  background-color: var(--bg4);
}

.production-block-5 {
  grid-row-start: 4;
  background-color: var(--bg5);
}

.production-container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
  .production-container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
    padding: 0 var(--standard-margin) 0 var(--standard-margin);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .production-container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
  .production-block-1 {
    grid-row-start: 1;
    height: 150px;
  }
  .production-block-2 {
    grid-row-start: 2;
    height: 200px;
  }
  .production-block-3 {
    grid-row-start: 3;
  }
  .production-block-4 {
    grid-row-start: 1;
    height: 300px;
  }
  .production-block-5 {
    grid-row-start: 2;
    height: 250px;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Grid template with blank spaces</h1>
<div class="production-container">
  <div class="production-block-1">1</div>
  <div class="production-block-2">2</div>
  <div class="production-block-3">3</div>
  <div class="production-block-4">4</div>
  <div class="production-block-5">5</div>
</div>
```

**My Solution (Masonry + break column)**

To avoid blank spaces, you have a solution based on [Masonry with flexbox](https://tobiasahlin.com/blog/masonry-with-css/) and add a [break column inside the HTML template](https://tobiasahlin.com/blog/flexbox-break-to-new-row/).

> Notice : That solution needs :
>
> 1. add a html tag with `break-column` class
> 2. use `height: 100%;` on wrappers html tags.
> 3. The orders of the biggest resolution is the order in the html template, it is for the smallest resolution, you change the order.

```css
*,
::after,
::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

:root {
  --bg1: hsl(34, 96%, 54%);
  --bg2: hsl(189, 99%, 60%);
  --bg3: hsl(345, 100%, 60%);
  --bg4: hsl(128, 65%, 48%);
  --bg5: hsl(210, 99%, 60%);
  --standard-margin: 1rem;
}

body, html{
    height: 100%;
}

.production-block-1,
.production-block-2,
.production-block-3,
.production-block-4,
.production-block-5 {
  height: min-content;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.production-block-1 {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  background-color: var(--bg1);
}

.production-block-2 {
  grid-row-start: 3;
  background-color: var(--bg2);
}

.production-block-3 {
  grid-row-start: 5;
  background-color: var(--bg3);
}

.production-block-4 {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  background-color: var(--bg4);
}

.production-block-5 {
  grid-row-start: 4;
  background-color: var(--bg5);
}

.production-container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
  .production-container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
    padding: 0 var(--standard-margin) 0 var(--standard-margin);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .production-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: column wrap;
      max-width: 1024px;
      height: 100%;
      background: linear-gradient( var(--text-light-color), var(--text-light-color) ) no-repeat center/1px 100%;
  }
  /* Force new columns */
 .production-container::before,
 .production-container::after {
    content: "";
    flex-basis: 100%;
    width: 0;
    order: 2;
  }
  .break-column {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    width: 0 !important;
  } 
  .production-container > .production-block{
    width: 500px;
  } 
  .production-block-1 {
    height: 150px;
  }
  .production-block-2 {
    height: 200px;
  }
  .production-block-4 {
    height: 300px;
  }
  .production-block-5 {
    height: 250px;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Masonry solution without blank space</h1>
<div class="production-container">
  <div class="production-block production-block-1">1</div>
  <div class="production-block production-block-2">2</div>
  <div class="production-block production-block-3">3</div>
  <div class="break-column"></div>
  <div class="production-block production-block-4">4</div>
  <div class="production-block production-block-5">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, your second snippet with flex can break into five columns if the window is not tall enough, if you remove height on the main container it also breaks into a single column ;) . not sure it is a good example. **requirement 2 stated : *(the height of the wrapper has to fit of the content ),***  The first snippet leaves blank space  !?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus, that´s why I add a notice with 3 requirements. It´s not a perfect solution as well.